# how to add HTML CMenu in yii

Tags: php, yii

Hope you are all doing well. I have been trying to implement CMenu in Yii template. I am using,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'collapse','id'=>'component-nav'),
));
```

And I want to dislpay my HTML output as

```
<li class=""><a href="icon.html"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i> List Registration </a></li>
```

But I can not insert this section: `<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>` beside the label i.e. "List Registration". Is there any way to insert this `<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>` html part beside every label of item.

Please help me someone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it easier to do this in your css stylesheet? I assume you want to display an icon (or any other image) next to the menu text? Is that correct?

Comment: @davey yes, I want to display an icon prior to the menu text. There are few alternatives but my design is built by this way. So I am trying to insert this HTML part in the menu. Do you have any idea or suggestion? Please comment on this post. Thanks

Comment: I understand, i don't think Yii provides a way to add a html element inside a <a></a> according to the class reference (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu).

If you want to do it the css way: `#component-nav li a { background: url('path/to/image.png') no-repeat; padding-left: 30px; }`

Comment: thanks for this information. Okay I'll do through CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick dirty way:

```
$this->menu = array_map(function($item){
        $item["label"] = "<i class='icon-angle-right'></i>" . $item["label"];
        $item["encodeLabel"] = false;
        return $item;
}, $this->menu);

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'collapse','id'=>'component-nav'),
));
```

Comment: thanks my friend for this help. I have done and it's an wonderful solution. Just I need to add line `$item["encodeLabel"] = false; `into
<br />
`$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'collapse','id'=>'component-nav'),
));`

Comment: Sorry, I accepted once it worked but do not know how it was changed. I am newer. However, I have accepted now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Information from http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/525/customizing-the-cmenu-widget/

1. Disable HTML encoding `'encodeLabel' => false,`
2. Submenu change class `'submenuHtmlOptions' => array('class' => 'dropdown-menu',)`
3. Use label property 
   `'label' => '<i class="icon-user"></i><span class="username">Admin</span> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>',` Very useful with bootstrap
4. Use YII url property for correct adress i.e. `'url' => array('site/logout'),`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Yii provides a way to add a html element inside a  according to the class reference (yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu). If you want to do it the css way:

```
#component-nav li a { 
     background: url('path/to/image.png') no-repeat; 
     padding-left: 30px; // depends of the width of your image 
}
```